# Using assign to define variable in scope of function

Tags: r

I have the following snippet

```
library(magrittr)
test_fun <- function(x) {
  foo <- x %>%
    assign("boo", .)
  boo
}

test_fun("hello") # I want this to return "hello"
# Error in test_fun("hello") : object 'boo' not found
```

I'd like to be able to assign values to names in the scope of the function. Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT:**

The reason behind the pipe here is that, in my actual use case, I'd like to save some intermediate result that can be referred to later on in the pipeline. Put another way, instead of writing e.g.

```
foo1 <- data %>% ...
foo2 <- foo1 %>% ...
foo3 <- some manipulation with foo1 and foo2
```

I can do something like

```
foo <- data %>% ... %>% (assign to foo2) %>% ... %>% some manipulation with foo2
```

I'm under the impression that this would be a "cleaner" way to code, but am happy to learn otherwise if it's not good practice.

Comment: Your use of `%>%` is a bit confusing here. I'm not certain if you are using it in the `dplyr`-sense (a `data.frame`) or more direct `magrittr` sense. Regardless, though this is truly a simple example, it would help to provide a little context such as if something else is being done to/with `x` (and/or other requirements). Otherwise, `{ boo <- x; boo; }` meets your strict needs (which I'm inferring is not what you need).

Comment: Please post all `library()` lines.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily recommend this (without more understanding of all the requirements), but the issue you are having is with the scope that `assign` sees at the time of execution. Regardless of where it is looking, what's important is that it *is* in fact assigning to a variable named `boo` but not in the scope of `test_fun` nor in a way that is easily retrievable later.

A quick solution might be to do something like:

```
test_fun <- function(x) {
    myenv <- environment()
    foo <- x %>%
        assign("boo", ., envir = myenv)
    # something else with 'foo'? side-effect? unknown ...
    boo
}
test_fun("hello")
# [1] "hello"
```

Since `assign` invisibly returns the value stored ("`.`" in your context), you should be able to keep the pipeline moving after it.